# What is the IQ of Raj?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In Big Bang Theory, Sheldon occasionally brags about his IQ which is very high (187), and his best friend Leonard has a whooping 173. Its clear Sheldon does not think Howard to be smart enough because he is mere engineer

However what is the IQ of Raj, because he is only one who gets the chance to work with Sheldon.

Comment: As far as I know, this has never been revealed either on the show or in any sort of interview with show runners/writers.

Comment: Raj never worked with Sheldon. He worked FOR Sheldon.

Comment: IQ if measured correctly has nothing to do with what you know (facts) and everything to do with your ability to learn new things or logically solve things.  There is a clear difference between being great at trivia, having a Rainman like photographic memory, and being able to solve complex things.  IQ is a measure of how complex can your brain think and how fast can it think.  It is definitely not a component of career success nor the ability to answer a factual based question.

Comment: Maybe Rajesh is not as bright as we think. He did think that mummies and zombies 'are basically the same'. It only took Sheldon and a cookie to prove him wrong.

Answer (score 13):

No IQ scores for either Raj or Howard have been stated. Sheldon has occasionally mentioned Raj having higher intelligence than Leonard (173), but nothing specific or official.

Answer (score 4):

Sheldon obviously considers Raj to be more intelligent than Leonard. It's demonstrated numerous times.

What's more Raj is arguably the most successful scientist of the 3. Certainly more successful than Leonard.

Raj is very close to Sheldon in IQ. Probably around 178-180.

Kripke is Sheldon's intellectual superior. He regularly surpasses Sheldon's work in their field, and outsmarts him, WITHOUT an eidetic memory. This would imply his base IQ is higher, to compensate for his physical disadvantage.

Comment: Speculation, no evidence on any statement.

Comment: Eiditic memory (that is what Sheldon claimes he has (but I think he is wrong on that one)).

Comment: Sheldon has Eidetic memory, the script writers do not, to the point they even forget Sheldon does @Bent

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it has never been mentioned on the show but I too have wondered what the others IQ's are. I believe that based on how Sheldon believed that Raj knew what the anthropic principle was and believed Leonard did not could mean that Raj may be possibly smarter than Leonard. I am a big fan of the show and think that the order of IQ is...

1. Sheldon (187)
2. Amy (between 180-185)
3. Kripke (maybe around 176-183)
4. Raj (between 174-179)
5. Leonard (173)
6. Bernadett (between 170-175)
7. Howard (between 160-165)
8. Stuart (maybe around 120-130)
9. Penny (maybe around 95-105)

Now this is completely based off of my opinion from watching the show, but I hope this helped.

Comment: If you can toss in something about how you arrive to these conclusions, that would make this a fantastic answer.

Comment: *"Sheldon believed that Raj knew what the anthropic principle was and believed Leonard did not"* - That could also be because he maybe thought an astrophysicist (like *Raj*) was much more likely to know about the anthropic principle (which is a common theme in cosmology) than an experimental physicist (like *Leonard*) and might have been one of *Sheldon*'s usual statements about experimental physics not being as relevant as theoretical physics. It need not necessarily have come from a general judgement of *Raj* being more intelligent than *Leonard*.

Comment: How have you arrived at these numbers?  I found an IQ distribution chart (here http://www.iqcomparisonsite.com/iqtable.aspx) and Stuart being one in 10 of the population is a stretch but believable. IQ doesn't equate to success, but he just runs a failing comic book store.  Howard at 160-165 is a stretch.  That is at the 1 in 30,000 - 1 in 130,000 region.  Howard is an intelligent engineer, but in the 7-30 people in a million region?  187 makes Sheldon one of one or two most intelligent people in the USA.

Comment: I would say that the IQ of Bernadett is way too big in your guess.

Comment: Penny's IQ is higher (110-115), she just never applied herself in school. She does not know much and makes (or rather made) bad choices in life. Throughout the series she has been seen to learn quickly. And remember the numbers most likely are based on a standard deviation of 25 or 26 not 15 or 16. The 25/26 std. dev. is traditional in Hollywood.

Answer (score -6):

Sheldon - 197
Lenard - 193
Amy (Sheldon finds her near equal)- 170 - 175
Kripke (Sheldon rival obviously close in intelligence)- 175 - 180
Raj (pretty much a guess, but he is an astrophysicists ) 155-160
Howard (engineers so pretty smart, but not an Einstein) 140 - 150
Bernadette (pretty much a guess, she develops drug "doesn't take a genius") - 125 - 135
Stuart (runs a comic book store "average") - 100 - 105
Penny (not too bright) - 87 - 100

Comment: Sheldon and Leonard's IQ are actually from the show, but the rest of these are just guesses.

Comment: Every single estimate is WRONG. [**Sheldon's IQ is 187**](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Sheldon) and [**Leonard's IQ is 173**](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Leonard_Hofstadter)